# How to create Outlook 365 Search Folder for Calendar Items

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, calendar

When creating a Search Folder in the Outlook 365 desktop app, the user is prompted to pick a folder to include in the search. Calendar does not appear in the dialog box -- only email message folders. Is there a way to create a Search Folder (i.e., saved search) that applies to appointment items stored in the Calendar folder associated with the main OST?

"Calendar" does not appear under the top-level OST/PST, so it's not possible to do this by just picking the Outlook store in question and check the box for all subfolders.

If this is impossible, what's the best workaround if there is a frequent complex search a user wants to run on Calendar?

Comment: I think what you must do is first select the calendar view.  Then in that view use the search box to find calendar items

Comment: That doesn't allow me to create Search Folder -- I understand how to search for calendar items, but am looking for a way to create an Outlook Search Folder that includes calendar items.

Comment: I posted the above because there does not appear to be a way to do what you wish.

Comment: I agree with John. There is currently no way to create an Outlook 365 search folder for calendar items.

Comment: Is there any alternative that would function as a "saved search" in calendar? I suppose I could write VBA corresponding to the search and execute that as a macro. Anything easier?

Comment: Searching for items in Outlook calendar can only be found by searching for specific words or some filters. You can also refine your search using quotation marks, AND, OR, or NOT operators, or filter icons.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: @soki that's not responsive -- I understand how to search in Outlook. The question is whether there is a way to create a search folder or something equivalent.